# SQL Join and Where Issue

Tags: sql

So im having the following issue, when i run the following query

```
SELECT ClientSubId,ClientType,ClientStatus,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,
  CityName,PostalCode,StateProvinceCode,
  ClientFirstName,ClientLastName, BillManagerName

FROM CLIENT
JOIN
CLIENTADDRESS
ON CLIENT.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent

JOIN 
CLIENTINDIVIDUAL
ON CLIENT.ClientIdent = CLIENTINDIVIDUAL.ClientIdent

JOIN
CLIENTPRACTICE
ON CLIENT.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent
```

Im getting back all results that match all fields, witch is correct, However when i apply the where clause at the end

```
WHERE
CLIENT.ClientIdSubId = '48079'
```

I get back no results. Im confused as to why i dont get back any results when i apply the Where clause, but without it i get all the results and that ID number is apart of those results.

[Results without the WHERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxFkF.png)

[Results With the Where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXaFZ.png)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Are you certain that `48079` is not in fact `48O79` ?

Comment: Does the `CLIENT` exists in with that `ClientIdSubId`? Did you try that simple query?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: CLIENT.ClientIdSubId = '48079' doesnt exists is the most likely scenario

Comment: Probably some white space in `CLIENT.ClientIdSubId` (if it's a `varchar`, if not, remove the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is pretty simple. I can only see two possible issues:

1. There's no `CLIENT` with `ClienIdSubId` that is equal to `'48079'`.
2. There is a `CLIENT` with that criteria, but there's no matching row in `CLIENTADDRESS`, in `CLIENTINDIVIDUAL`, or `CLIENTPRACTICE`. Make sure there are matching rows on each table since you are using **INNER JOINS**.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all i had the right query ClientIdSubId was suppose to be ClientSubId. Instead of ClientIdSubId.